# Why are rails gems not using the same gem and library names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, naming-conventions

Maybe it's just because it's late at night, but I just spent way too long figuring out that while the gem is `activesupport`, you need to `require 'active_support'`. This is the same for `activerecord`, `actionmailer`, and all the other rails libraries defined in https://github.com/rails/rails (so at least it's internally consistent).

Is there a historical reason for this, or any benefits to it?

Comment: There's certainly no benefit to it, it's annoying and stupid. Also relevant: http://blog.segment7.net/2009/05/20/a-project-naming-recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, this change was a deprecation warning going to Rails 3 (started in Rails 2.3.2?).  There is no real advantage or anything.  It's legacy (yes confusing).  You can see the commit here that adds the deprecation warnings:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/08d15f86c447fea31132d11df03ff5df41650f50#diff-2

Devs cheering in the comments.

Really it was renaming (or zero'ing out) lib/activerecord.rb to lib/active_record.rb etc.  That's the history and no one liked it.  Lately, it's been less of a hot topic since most people have heard about it or run into by now.  However, I'm sure I'd get this warning/error if I upgraded one of my really old Rails projects.  Sorry if this was annoying for you, I've been there too.  :)